# Thermochemical data of methanol

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I am trying to find the standard entropy and enthalpy of methanol as functions of temperature, but they are not available on the NIST-JANAF tables: http://kinetics.nist.gov/janaf/

Does anyone know where I could possibly find the data?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: http://wtt-lite.nist.gov/wtt-lite/index.html?cmp=methanol#methanol/A;0,0,508,415;help,about/aa2;50,50,508,415/aa1;491,97,508,415/

Comment: Thanks for responding! Do I need to log in to view the data?

Comment: as far as I know you don't. I thought when I looked that I could view things without a login.

Comment: I took a look again and it doesn't seem to show me any data besides the molecule, property availability, and help tabs. In no place does it say how to access the properties. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

[NIST Webbook Chemistry](https://webbook.nist.gov/) is a reference which I would recommend as a first (as in *initial*) resource to consult for enthalpies of small organic molecular and inorganic materials.  The entry about [methanol](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Name=methanol&Units=SI&cTC=on) lists for one temperature the value in question, the experimental method of acquisition, and the primary literature reference.  The later may contain more data than the one tabulated here, too.

The references might be old, but in a scientific library you will find assistance to figure out who cited these publications which in turn may lead you to more recent determinations.